# Logic app not creating and showing an error on adding first action

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, azure-logic-apps

Hey I am trying to create a new Logic app from visual studio 2019 and whenever I create a new Logic app and try to add a recurrence trigger as the first action I get an error for Script on page.

[image: 1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have received the same error after reproducing from my end. AFAIK, you are receiving this because of the Active Scripting / Active X is enabled for Internet Explorer.

#### **STEP - 1: Disable Active Scripting**

To make it disabled, Navigate to ***Tools >> Options >> Environment (Web Browser) >> Security >> Custom Level >> Scripting >> Disabled***. ActiveX Filtering can sometimes prevent few services from properly loading if it is enabled.

[image]

#### **STEP - 2: Start with an empty template**

This might be a bug as because when I select the trigger directly from the template page it is not generating its relevant JSON. To overcome this issue, after step-1 try starting your flow with Blank Logic app template and then add recurrence trigger.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks alot, Visual studio used  to prompt some scripting errors while working as well. I guess this would stop those errors as well